# Cart Total with Shipping

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to find out the total price based on the product quantity,
I am saving quantity and price in database following is the query that i am using to find out the total price

```
SELECT SUM( price * quantity ) AS subtotal, SUM( quantity ) AS qty
FROM  `cart` 
WHERE user
IN (

SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE email =  'test'
)
```

Now what i want , i need add shipping charges, if the quantity is 1-5 than shipping charges would be 50 and if 6-10 than it would be 100 ad so on

How can i achieve this ? this is what i am trying but wrong! Please find me a solution.

```
 $subtotalquery=" SELECT SUM( price * quantity ) as subtotal, SUM(quantity) as qty FROM  `cart` WHERE user IN  (select id from users where email='$user_check')";
                                $t_con=$conn->query($subtotalquery);
                                $subtotalrow = $t_con->fetch_assoc();

                                $subtotal= $subtotalrow['subtotal'];
                                $qty= $subtotalrow['qty'];
                                if($qty>=5)
                                {
                                    $shipping=50 ;

                                    $ithship=$subtotalrow+($shipping);

                                }else
                                {
                                $shipping=50*2 ;

                                    $ithship=$subtotalrow+($shipping*2);
}
```

Comment: was your problem solved ? if yes then acknowledge the answer by accepting them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, You need to add shipping charge into subtotal

```
if($qty<=5)
{
    $shipping=50 ;
}else
{
$shipping=50*2 ;
}
$ithship=$subtotal+$shipping; // add to  subtotal
```

**EDIT**

if you want to increase shipping charge on every 5+ qty. try below code

```
$qty= $subtotalrow['qty'];
$incr  = ceil($qty/5);
$shipping = $incr*50;
echo $shipping;
```

**EDIT** 
You can achieve this using sql query also :

```
SELECT SUM( price * quantity ) as subtotal, SUM(quantity) as qty, ((ceil(SUM(quantity)/5))*50) as ShippingCharge FROM  `cart` WHERE user IN  (select id from users where email='$user_check');
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31ac7/2)

Comment: what is your expected op?

Comment: it is showing 50 as shipping price and total is also wrong, i tried incraesing the quantity to 15

Comment: I want 50 shipping charges on 1-5 quantity of product and it should be increased every 5+ quantity, like if the quantity is 6-10 then the shipping would be 100 and if 10-15 it would be 150.

Comment: Now it is showing only 100 it should increase every 5+

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE` statement instead

```
SELECT SUM(price * quantity) AS subtotal,
SUM(quantity) as quantity, 
CASE 
  WHEN SUM(quantity) <=5 THEN
  50
  WHEN SUM(quantity) BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN
  100
  ELSE
  150
  END as ShippingCharge
from  `cart` 
WHERE user
IN 
(
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE email =  'test'
)
```

**[>>>Demo<<<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9ab47f/1)**

Comment: You have applied the 150 on above 10 quantity, what if the quantity is 15 then it should be 200

Comment: @raman I have given you a sample code. You need to add code accordingly. Let me know, if you have specific question